# No module named tensorflow while i installed it with pip

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow and machine learning. I'm following some tutorials on my PC, and everything worked just fine so far, importation and test with python are OK. I tried to test my code on my Macbook. So I installed Tensorflow, Matplotlib and Pandas using Pip3 on the command prompt. But when I ran the code on my Mac I got this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
import tensorflow as ts
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

There are the output and the Pip3 list :

[Result of the pip install tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gWWY.jpg)

```
pip3 show tensorflow
```

gave me :

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.0.0a0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: google-pasta, gast, absl-py, astor, keras-preprocessing, keras-applications, six,           numpy, wheel, grpcio, protobuf, tf-estimator-nightly, termcolor, tb-nightly
Required-by:
```

And :

```
pip3 list
```

gave me :

```
Package              Version
-------------------- --------------------
absl-py              0.8.0
astor                0.8.0
cycler               0.10.0
gast                 0.3.2
google-pasta         0.1.7
grpcio               1.23.0
h5py                 2.10.0
Keras-Applications   1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0
kiwisolver           1.1.0
Markdown             3.1.1
matplotlib           3.1.1
numpy                1.17.2
pandas               0.25.1
pip                  19.1.1
protobuf             3.9.1
pyparsing            2.4.2
python-dateutil      2.8.0
pytz                 2019.2
setuptools           41.0.1
six                  1.12.0
tb-nightly           1.14.0a20190301
tensorflow           2.0.0a0
termcolor            1.1.0
tf-estimator-nightly 1.14.0.dev2019030115
virtualenv           16.7.5
Werkzeug             0.15.6
wheel                0.33.4
```

I did the exact same things on my Mac that I did on my PC, but I have more than one version of Python on my Mac, maybe this is the problem, but I just don't know how to solve it.

Sorry for my English, I'm not quit used to post on forum like these, and thanks for your help, I can give more information on my problem if you want.

Comment: On your Mac, are you using `python test.py` or `python3 test.py` to run this code?

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and pip3 can install module for one Python but you run code with other Python. if you use `python` to run code then maybe you should use `pip` to install module. Or use `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: I tested with both python and python3, neither of these commands are working for me... I don't know if it is relevant, but it's the first time I'm really using pip, I was coding with PyCharm before, and the module in pip3 is showing a différent list of module than the module in my PyCharm

Comment: Use either pip or pip3 to install tensorflow. Create virtual environment `python3 -m venv --system-site-packages` and activate the environment `source ./venv/bin/activate`and upgrade pip packages `pip install --upgrade pip` now install tensorflow `pip install tensorflow`. Thanks!